Does not restore connection after disconnecting and connecting network bridge
Disconnecting the network bridge and reconnecting it (using the GUI or nmcli command) does not restore the network connection. The brctl command shows that no interface is connected to the bridge.  Only restarting the NetworkManager (systemctl restart NetworkManager) restores the connection.
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-40-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 12 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11600 @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
Product Name: MS-7D18
System Version: 1.0


Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

The command nmcli con up enp3s0 reactivates the connection, which means it's the fault of the interfaces I guess
